# Improving automatic half-bounty rule?

Tags: discussion, bounty, upvotes

**Disclaimer:** This is in reference to
[Hotkey for running command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457366/hotkey-for-running-command/), but please consider it outside these specifics. I am just trying to understand this general case:

Question asked, bounty eventually placed. (**Edit:** Once bounty is made, it is gone, no problem there, really.)

A single answerer makes some attempts to provide an answer. The solutions don't seem to work.

Asker answers own question independently. (**Edit:** Still call this person the 'asker'.)

There is something good to be said for the answerer's reply, and, for the effort, the asker upvotes the answerer so that they receive some points.

The answerer's reply goes to vote of 2.

Now the answerer will automatically receive half the bounty, plus the original points given. The issue would seem to be that the original points were awarded because the bounty was not. But now both are being awarded. This might discourage the asker from awarding any points to the answerer. (In my case, I didn't mind, since the points were being given to a new member, and I was losing the points anyway.) On the plus side, it does at least get some kind of response to questions with no replies, but it seems to encourage just saying anything that comes to mind, along with 'this will work', which can be more frustrating to the asker than no reply.

If anyone agrees that this is not ideal for encouraging answers that work, **is there a better way?** I have not thought of one, but I am not versed in the rules of SO. Maybe some way to award points without upvoting an answer. Or maybe moving the half-bounty requirement to 3 votes. (**Edit:** One possibility mentioned in comments was an *'award bounty to no one'* button, but it was noted it would depend on the good intentions of the user.)

Comment: I vaugely remember reading that the person who created the bounty can't be awarded it.

Comment: @KevinBrown The way I'm reading, the OP means when they don't want the bounty awarded to any answer, even if they meet the requirement to automatically receive the bounty, not that they want to award it to their post. I can see where this could be a useful feature, a "do not award" button or something. I can also see how it could be misused.

Comment: That's correct; once bounty is made, it is gone, no problem there, really. Kendra's statement is what I mean.

Comment: You may wish to make that a bit more clear in your post- At first, I was misunderstanding it as well. Perhaps explicitly mentioning a way of awarding a bounty to no one.

Comment: My bad, I _completely missed_ the fact that dwn was the person who asked both questions.

Comment: If you dont want to award the bounty to someone for a good reason, dont award it.  The half-award needs to stay in place for good answers where the poster wanders off and forgets to award it, or simply doesnt want to for one reason or another.

Comment: Hopefully someone wouldn't just kill a bounty as they wandered off, but 'simply doesn't want to' I do see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is why the asker shouldn't be upvoting answers that fail to answer the question.  Had they downvoted the answer that failed to actually answer the question as they should have, then there wouldn't have been a problem.

**The asker** made the decision to reward someone for providing a low quality contribution.

Of note, if the asker were to downvote the post, and the post would still end up with a score of 2 or more due to other community votes, then it being awarded the bounty, even if the asker (or bounty awarder, which are the same in this case) didn't think it answered the question.  This is *also* by design.

Comment: I can understand the sense in the last paragraph, so I'm considering this an acceptable justification for the current spec. If there are any points others might want to add to this topic, hopefully they will feel free to do so.